# How to Add Splashscreen in Windows Phone SIlverlight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

So I ran into the following error during the certification process.

[image]

I have updated the icons, but I noticed that there is only one splash screen image. I need to create individual splash screens for each device screen size in order to keep aspect ratios on my splash screen design intact. In following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx it states how to name the splash screens and to place them in the root folder of the project. The default splash screen that was detected is actually in the Assets folder within the root folder. Where can I place these so that the certification process will detect them. Also, should I remove the default splash screen image from the solution?

Comment: This one could be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that is the link I referenced in the original question. My question is that it says to place the splash screen images in the root, although in the Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 template the `Splashscreen.png` file is located in the `Assets` folder within the root, and is also a png, so this is confusing on what exactly to do.

Comment: I guess it should be within the Assets folder, as they've included it within that, and also according to the error it says that you've not replaced with the default Splashscreen. Did you change it?

Comment: Ok so I discovered the default Splashscreen.png is 1152x1920 which is pretty large and doesn't match any phone screen size from the msdn page. I didn't want to deviate from this so I made a single new splash screen image to replace the one in the Assets folder and it seemed to have passed that stage in the certification process. I could not tell though using the emulators and my device whether the updated SplashScreen.png image I included was stretched because the app loaded so fast, so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a single image as splash screen, you should add an image file that is **768 × 1,280** and named **SplashScreenImage.jpg** to your app **project's root folder.**

The phone automatically scales the image to the correct size.

Comment: Ok, so why is the default image twice that size but with the same aspect ratio, and located in the default created Assets folder? Previously with another WP8.0 solution I did place the three splashscreen images with the correct naming scheme in the root, but with the WP8.1 Silverlight template this is different, the default splashscreen was in the Assets folder and not a jpg but a png named SplashScreen.png

Comment: if you are takling about SplashScreen.scale-240.png so that has not size as General Splashscreen's size Recommended. Try above thing. Template is Different but for SplashScreen its same as Before. the link that you have provide has clearly instructions and it also applies to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 also.